# C++ Why do I need to specify the scope of a function in an extended class?

Tags: c++

The class:

```
template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
class ExtAvlTree : public AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> {
    public:
        void ExtAvlTree_PrintDictionary();
        void ExtAvlTree_ProcessNode (KTYPE key);
        void ExtAvlTree_insertNewWord(string, int);
};
```

When I want to use a function in AvlTree I have to do this:

```
template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
void ExtAvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>::ExtAvlTree_insertNewWord(string word, int data) {
    TreeNode newWord;
    newWord.key = word;
    newWord.data = data;
    AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>::AVL_Insert(newWord); //look here <--
}
```

If I dont specify the scope "AvlTree::" I get an error:

```
error: there are no arguments to 'AVL_Insert' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'AVL_Insert' must be available [-fpermissive]|
```

From my knowledge when using functions from a base class in a derived class i dont have to specify the scope. If it matters I am using codeblocks 16.01 IDE.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that the code in question uses **templates**, so analysis of "using functions from a base **class**" can be misleading. Templates are not classes; they are **patterns** for creating classes, They have a set of rules for making template instantiation sensible, and those rules don't apply to classes.

Answer (score 1):

> From my knowledge when using functions from a base class in a derived class i dont have to specify the scope.

It's true for non-templated classes because there such lookup is uniquely defined. In this case you're using templated classes so the lookup of `AvlTree` doesn't uniquely define a type. In fact, `AvlTree` itself isn't even a type but describes a set of types that can be created with different template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The base class `AvlTree` is not a nondependent base class, and `AVL_Insert` is a nondependent name. The nondependent names are not looked up in dependent base classes.

To correct this code you need to make the name `AVL_Insert` dependent because dependent names can be looked up only at the time of instantiation. At that time the exact base specialization that must be explored will be known.

As you showed, you can

```
AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>::AVL_Insert(newWord);
```

or use `this`,

```
this->AVL_Insert(newWord);
```

or use `using`,

```
using AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>::AVL_Insert;
AVL_Insert(newWord);
```